# Sending data from childwindow to parentwindow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I did a small library HomeDAL where I have a class with functions like connect,disconnect,add,delete,showbooks etc. to manage my database.

Now I'm doing a client in WPF.  In `MainWindow`, I have a variable of this class from my HomeDAL, and I have a `Button` "Add new record".  Clicking on this button opens a new window, where I have some `TextBox`es to describe the new record and a `Button` "Make".  Clicking this "Make" button, I close the second window.

I want to use the variable `HomeDAL` in `MainWindow` to run one of their functions but it doesn't work, and the application crashes.

Below is a function I have in the second window:

```
private void btnOkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow test = (MainWindow)this.Parent;
    Book newBook = new Book()
    {
        Tytul = tbTytul.Text,
        Autor = tbAutor.Text,
        Cena = Int32.Parse(tbCena.Text),
        Przeczytane = tbPrzeczytane.Text
    };
    test.SqlConn.InsertBook(newBook);
    this.Close();
}
```

Any tip as to why my program crashes?

Comment: Whats the error ? which line ?

Comment: When i took the whole function in try catch block it write : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: In fact i don't know, in VS there is no any errors, just Exception in MessageBox writes about it. Probably "test.SqlConn.InsertBook(newBook);" thats the problem because after I have comented it, app doesnt crash.

Comment: Try: `MainWindow test = this.Owner as MainWindow;` instead.
Also if in visual studio, place a breakpoint in this line in step into it, might help you understand the error better.

Comment: Thanks but still the same :/

Comment: Ok problem solved. I did "public MainWindow parent = null;" in the child window, and before showing the second window i set the parent from MainWindow, using the parent in childwindow is working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a DAL layer in your application, i would suggest the following based on

1. your presentation tier will be the `MainWindow`
2. DataAccessLayer will be `HomeDAL`.

The steps will be

- When you click on the `Make` button as you have now, you will create an object of `Book` type and populate the values.
- You will create an object for the `HomeDAL` like `var dal = new HomeDAL()` or using some IOC like `Unity`.
- Then pass the newly created book object to the DAL so that the DAL layer can persist the data in the database.

Note: Page is an object that is created for each request and you will not have to mix up the data access with your presentation tier, given you already have the DAL layer.

In this case, your sample will look like this

```
 private void btnOkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Book newBook = new Book()
    {
        Tytul = tbTytul.Text,
        Autor = tbAutor.Text,
        Cena = Int32.Parse(tbCena.Text),
        Przeczytane = tbPrzeczytane.Text
    };
    var dal = new HomeDAL(); // pass any initialization parameters if required for the DAL to self initialize.
    var newBookId = dal.CreateBook(newBook);
    // use some mechanism to show the newly created book id to the user or else redirect the user to the grid that shows the books sorted by creation date so that the book he created now will be shown as the first one.

}
```

Please let us know your understanding of this implementation and share your ideas.